# How to combine values in dict to new key/value pair, replacing None with empty string?

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary (d) like so:

```
d = { 
'[primary_number]': '12345', 
'[street_name]': 'Main', 
'[street_predirection]': 'NW', 
'[street_postdirection]': None, 
'[street_suffix]': 'St', 
'[secondary_number]': None, 
'[secondary_designator]': None, 
'[extra_secondary_number]': None,
'[zipcode]': '12345'
}
```

And I would like to create a new Key/Value pair called AddressStr that combines several (but not all) of the fields in d. I am trying to combine it with the following code:

```
d['AddressStr'] = d["[zipcode]"] + \
    d["[street_name]"] + \
    d["[primary_number]"] + \
    d["[secondary_number]"] + \
    d["[street_predirection]"] + \
    d["[street_postdirection]"] + \
    d["[street_suffix]"]
```

However, this produces the error:

```
can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Because `[street_postdirection]` = `None`. Ideally, I would like to just have a check/replace to change the None values in those 7 fields to `''`, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. I'd also like to do in place during the creation of `d['AddressStr']`, but if that's not possible I'm OK with that.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this, in what context? It seems slightly odd.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I am combining the address fields to create unique address hashes as an alternative to joining datasets on multiple fields which may or may not have nulls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `join` the values that are not `None`:

```
keys = ["[zipcode]", "[street_name]", "[primary_number]",
        "[secondary_number]", "[street_predirection]", "[street_postdirection]",
        "[street_suffix]"]

d['AddressStr'] = ' '.join([d[key] for key in keys if d[key] is not None])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the str() method and use the property that None behaves as false on a boolean check:

```
d['AddressStr'] = str(d["[zipcode]"] or '') + \
str(d["[street_name]"] or '') + \
str(d["[primary_number]"] or '') + \
str(d["[secondary_number]"] or '') + \
str(d["[street_predirection]"] or '') + \
str(d["[street_postdirection]"] or '') + \
str(d["[street_suffix]"] or '')
```